# How to get text response from alexa voice service

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-presentation-language

I'm using following python library to query alexa voice service.
https://pypi.org/project/avs-client/

In request I send audio file and in response I receive audio file.

1. How to get text response using the above mentioned library ?
2. How to connect to AVS directly and get the text and audio response ?

Comment: This library is used by a virtual Alexa (in a browser). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BelaVizy I want to send an audio file to AVS and get audio and text response in return.